# Database First EntityType 'table' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I Create the model starting from a Oracle Database. In the table that I picked there isn't a primary key so the entity framework complains about that and it is not able to generate the classes correctly.
Do you know a way to generate the model in the correct way without adding the primary key to the database?

Comment: You will have to manually create the object, and it should work. If your table doesn't have at least a Primary Key, then chances are the DB has been poorly defined. After all that's the point of a Relational Database. The Primary Key makes the Relationship at the very least. Even if it's a standalone table, it should still have a PK

Answer (score 0):

One way of adding a primary key to a table after you have created your model is to open this file [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vJhP.png. Once inside you will see all the relevant tables on the model. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSIsK.png. Right click on the column you wish to make the primary key, you will see the wording "Entity Key", make sure this is ticked/selected as in the image. Save the model, and rebuild project. This should be done on all tables complaining of primary keys. Hope it helps.